# BlueStacks physical keyboard keeps getting ticked ON

Tags: bluestacks

I like to have the "physical keyboard" disabled, in order to make appear the virtual keyboard which contains all the Android smileys. However, every time BlueStacks closes or goes to trail (when computer sleeps), the "physical keyboard" is set on ON again, disabling the virtual one.. quite annoying to change that otpion every time i need the smileys

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Which version of bluestacks are you using?

Comment: The latest one right now, can't find a number or something, just "the latest one"

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below steps and the onscreen keyboard was always displayed no matter I restart the Bluestack/it went to tray/even after system restart. Based on Bluestacks support page about [How to enable/disable on screen keyboard?](http://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/204274235-How-to-enable-disable-on-screen-keyboard-)

1. On the home screen click on the All Apps on the top-right corner.
2. Click on 'Select IME' app.
3. To enable on-screen keyboard and, please click on 'Enable OnScreen Keyboard'.

[image: Screenshot_Bluestacks_Onscreen_keyboard]

The above steps only enables the on-screen keyboard everytime you click on an text field. This doesnot disable the typing throught physical keyboard though. You can use both the hardware and the virtual on-screen keyboard at the same time. If you still have the hardware keyboard enable after every restart, then re-install the bluestacks app.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to solve my problem. It's like it would set the "onscreen keyboard" option to "off" every time, like a default value. Isn't there a way to go change some boolean value somewhere in some config file ?

Comment: IDK, its completely working even after the PC restart for me @Paul. Maybe there's something wrong with your installation/data of bluestacks or something might have corrupted. Do a fresh installation of Bluestacks latest version and see if that helps.